# After deployment of GAE Flexible Go project, pubsub will stop working for about 15-20 mins?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Our App Engine Go flexible projects, whenever we deploy successfully, we lose the ability to publish message to PubSub for about 15-20 mins. 
After 15-20 mins, it starts working again! 
We start to suspect, that this is a bug on the platform. 
I'm wondering if anyone of you experienced the same issue and how to avoid it?

Thanks

[Edit]: 
After the request hung, the thread finally spit out tcp timeout error :-(

Could not publish message: Post https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxxx-xxxx-844/topics/yyyyxxxx:publish?alt=json: read tcp 172.17.0.4:39416->74.125.70.95:443: read: connection timed out

Comment: What types of errors are you getting on your publish requests?

Comment: There was no errors from pubsub client library. The request simply hung. We added log.Debugf around it. It stops at the line. if _, err := topic.Publish(ctx, msg); err != nil { return fmt.Errorf("Could not publish message: %v", err) }

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn Hi Kamal, actually the hung request finally spit out tcp timeout error. 
Could not publish message: Post https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxxx-xxxx-844/topics/yyyyxxxx:publish?alt=json: read tcp 172.17.0.4:39416->74.125.70.95:443: read: connection timed out

Comment: If you can provide a way to reproduce this, I'd advise opening a defect report on the [google-cloud-platform](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list) issue tracker so we can take a look at it.